# Invalid address: return even on successfully sent e-mail

Tags: 7, emails

Need help ASAP.
My function is sending e-mail on successful quit. E-mail is sent well. The problem is that i'm always getting "Invalid address:" before my normal exit message.
Code is following:

```
$message_text = array(
'id' => 'modulename' . '_' . 'key',
'to' => '2@example.com',
'subject' => "OK",
'body' => array("OK"),
'headers' => array(
    'From' => '1@example.com',
    'Sender' => '1@example.com',
    'Return-Path' => '1@example.com',
          ),
);
$system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
$message = $system->format($message_text);
$system->mail($message);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well. Not the best solution. I know, but currently I managed to avoid this by cleaning output buffer with ob_clean();

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the absence of $message_text['from'];
In SMTP module smtp.module.inc line 74-85 there is hack that handles the absence of 'Reply-To' by setting it to $message['from'] which is also absent, consequently 'Reply-To' will be empty hence throwing the error Invalid address:.
add $message_text['from'] = 'your from address' this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try at last

```
$system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
if ($system->mail($message)) {
  // Success.
}
else {
  // Failure.
}
```